# Dominant vs. Dominate as an adjective

Tags: word-choice

In a story about the cultural divide, an author writes about the "white-dominate society." I intend to change it to "dominant" in this example. Is that correct?

Comment: Read something different. Your author is either careless or a non-native speaker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns either a typographical or a transcription error.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Or a diction error. I encounter *dominate* for *dominant* distressingly often.

Answer (score 1):

They might have meant to write "white-dominated." "White-dominant" and "white-dominated" have pretty much the same meaning. Some people might feel the latter implies whites are actively dominating other people (to their misfortune), but I don't. They seem pretty much the same.

Comment: Your political views, however profound and illuminating the may seem to you, are of no value to students of English.

Comment: Political views? Whoa there, cowboy. Where are you getting THAT from? I told them about how some people might feel, but that others including me do not. Your objection tells more about your political views than my answer (and, I suspect, my user name) ever would about mine.

Answer (score 1):

That is jargon for a society where whites dominate.

Please consult a dictionary for **dominate**, **dominant**,  **predominate** and **predominant**, and decide accordingly.